# Reflection metadata 'design:paramtypes' returning undefined on Deno

Tags: typescript, reflection, metadata, decorator, deno

I am trying to implement a dependency injection in typescript using [Deno](https://deno.land/), however, I have been getting a problem with `Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', ...)` that is returning an `undefined` value and I don't understand why.

```
Deno 1.6.0
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
```

I am using This file as Reflect: https://github.com/edualb/dependencyInjectionPOC/blob/main/Reflect.ts

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
  }
}
```

### Code

`decorator.ts`

```js
export interface Type<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}

export function Injectable(): (target: Type<any>) => void {
    return (target: Type<any>) => {}
}
```

`service2.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from './decorator.ts';

@Injectable()
export class Service2 {
    constructor() {}
}
```

`service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from './decorator.ts';
import { Service2 } from './service2.ts';

@Injectable()
export class Service {
    constructor(private s2: Service2) {}
}
```

`main.ts`

```js
import { Reflect } from './Reflect.ts';
import { Service } from './service.ts';

console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', Service)) // here is returning undefined
```

Command using to execute:

```sh
$ deno run main.ts
```

Github: https://github.com/edualb/dependencyInjectionPOC

Would have anyone can help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue putting the flag `-c` / `--config` in the execute command:

```sh
$ deno run -c tsconfig.json main.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://deno.land/manual@v1.32.1/advanced/typescript/configuration :

It is recommended to use `deno.json` instead of `tsconfig.json` …

A minimal example for `deno.json` :

```
{    
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "preact"
  }
}
```

then things like
`Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);` etc. work.